# How can we provide horizontal spacing between buttons using auto-layouts(constraint with visual formate)

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am trying to insert three button programmatically  on my view-controller using auto-layouts and here i would like keep horizontal spacing between buttons "10" but it is not setting properly please help me using constraint with "visual formate"

### my code:-

```
NSDictionary * views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(accessoryView,leftButton,firstButton,rightButton);

     //middle button
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:40.f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:firstButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        //Left button
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:40.f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:leftButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        //Right button
        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:40.f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:50.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:rightButton attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem: nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:30.0f];
        [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

        //Horizental spacing
        NSArray * horizontalConstraintsforbuttons = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[leftButton]-10-[firstButton]-10-[rightButton]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views];

        [self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraintsforbuttons];
```

Comment: You can try some alternatives like [PureLayout](https://github.com/smileyborg/PureLayout) or [Masonry](https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) which provide more developer friendly APIs.

Comment: [Here](http://www.knowstack.com/swift-autolayout-visual-format-language-sample-code/) it is

Answer (score 0):

Try this.... give button1 trailing equal button2 leading with constant whatever you want

```
// btn1.trailing = btn2.leading
[self.view  addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn2
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:btn1
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:10]];


 // btn2.trailing = btn3.leading
[self.view  addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn3
                                                       attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                                                       relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                           toItem:btn2
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                                                      multiplier:1
                                                        constant:10]];
```

So it becomes `-|btn1|-10-|btn2|-10-|btn3|-`

Comment: nice answer thanks if you dont ind can you provide visual formate for this issue